# Значения по умолчанию в моделях EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, codefirst

Создал проект на asp.net mvc. Создаю модели с помощью code-first entity framework. Мне необходимо, что бы было у одного из полей значение по умолчанию.
Вот моя модель:

```
public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Возраст")]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Роль")]
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

После того как я создал миграцию, вот что мне создал EF.

```
namespace WebApplication3.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class CreateDB : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Clients",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false),
                        Age = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Role = c.String(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.Clients");
        }
    }
}
```

Я дописываю для поля Role дефолтное значение.

`Role = c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "Пользователь"),`
Но при этом когда я пишу `update-database`, создаётся таблица, но вместо моего дефолтного значения выходит вот такое вот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю поехала кодировка. Попробовал добавить в конец строки подключения charset UTF8, но при попытке создания миграции выдаёт ошибку что ключевое слово charset не известно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно этого избежать? Как сделать так что бы дефолтное значение нормально отображалось на русском языке?

Comment: А в какой кодировке файл миграции (в котором Вы пишите "Пользователь")?

Comment: @XelaNimed там не написано в файле про кодировку, типо как в web config. Если вы об этом? я скинул всё содержимое файла. Или можно как то по другому посмотреть кодировку этого файла?

Comment: Откройте файл в блокноте и выберите "Сохранить как..." в открывшемся окне внизу Вы увидите кодировку файла...

Comment: А нет противоречия между Required и Default? Я имею ввиду - будет ли записано когда-нибудь значение default, если столбец не поддерживает значения NULL?

Comment: @XelaNimed на счёт этого не знаю, хотел как раз это проверить. Но пока кодировку не могу проверить. А кодировку нужно менять у файла где код создания моих моей таблицы или общего файла миграции тоже нужно?

Comment: @XelaNimed на всякий случай сохранил все файлы в UTF-8 не помогло. Может всё же нужно как то в connection string utf-8 прицепить? Или нужно в unicode кодировку ставить?

Comment: @XelaNimed вообщем и в юникод попробовал, не как не получается. Ума не приложу как сделать так что бы можно было дефолтными значениями русские символы заносить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91968/discussion-between-xelanimed-and-).